# Cleaning tibble data frame where some values are vectors without a loop

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Good day,

I have a table data frame with two columns where some of the entries in a given cell are a vector of the form c(x1, x2, ...). From column 1, I would like to extract the *maximum* value of the vector for that cell and then from column 2 return the value associated with the position of that maximum value from column 1.

I have the following screenshot showing an example of the data:

[image]

In the first row, the first column, the max is 7654.28 and that’s the 1st element of the vector so I need to return the 1st element from column 2 which is 152.

In the third row, the first column, the max is 7658.12 and that’s the 2nd element of the vector so I need to return the 2nd element from column 2 which is 435.

As such, the end result output should be:

```
7654.28 | 152
NULL | NULL
7658.12 | 435
```

I would like to achieve this without a loop as the data set is quite large and this would take forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things that you can do to make this easier to solve together.

1. Make a reproducible problem.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
df$v1<-list(c(7654.28,7651.4),NA,c(7652.36,7658.12,7653.32))
df$v2<-(list(c(152,944),NA,c(983,435,1000)))
```

2. Realize that list-columns are a little different, and using rowwise is helpful. Otherwise your operations will work up and down the columns instead of across the rows.
3. Understand match (which gives you the index of a value in a vector) and nth (which gives you the nth value of a vector.

So then you have

```
result<-df %>%    
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(max_v1=max(v1),value_v2_at_pos_max_v1=nth(v2,match(max(v1),v1)))
```